# I lost the get-apt update ability

Tags: command-line, apt, 20.04

I'm not sure what I did here, but I am getting the error messages:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get update
sudo: apt-get: command not found

:~$ sudo adduser ihansen
sudo: adduser: command not found

:~$ sudo /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo: /etc/apt/sources.list: com`

sudo: dpkg: command not found
```

Whatever I did I also lost sudo access as well. I was able to restore sudo access but now I am faced with this issue. I am new to Linux and any help is appreciated. Since I'm a beginner can you please list out all the steps if there is a solution.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Focal.

Thank you for your help!

```
:~$ sudo /usr/bin/sudo -l

Matching Defaults entries for root on ubuntuserver:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbi$

User root may run the following commands on ubuntuserver:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

##############################################################

```
:~$ cd /var/backups && ls
alternatives.tar.0        dpkg.diversions.1.gz    dpkg.statoverride.6.gz
alternatives.tar.1.gz     dpkg.diversions.2.gz    dpkg.status.0
alternatives.tar.2.gz     dpkg.diversions.3.gz    dpkg.status.1.gz
alternatives.tar.3.gz     dpkg.diversions.4.gz    dpkg.status.2.gz
apt.extended_states.0     dpkg.diversions.5.gz    dpkg.status.3.gz
apt.extended_states.1.gz  dpkg.diversions.6.gz    dpkg.status.4.gz
apt.extended_states.2.gz  dpkg.statoverride.0     dpkg.status.5.gz
apt.extended_states.3.gz  dpkg.statoverride.1.gz  dpkg.status.6.gz
apt.extended_states.4.gz  dpkg.statoverride.2.gz  group.bak
apt.extended_states.5.gz  dpkg.statoverride.3.gz  gshadow.bak
apt.extended_states.6.gz  dpkg.statoverride.4.gz  passwd.bak
dpkg.diversions.0         dpkg.statoverride.5.gz  shadow.bak
```

#################################################################

```
:~$ cd /var/lib/dpkg && ls
alternatives  diversions      lock           statoverride      status-old
available     diversions-old  lock-frontend  statoverride-old  triggers
cmethopt      info            parts          status            updates
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126489/discussion-between-eddie-v-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: `:/usr/sbi$` <-- fishy

Comment: @JonSkeet the 'user' functionality of move to chat doesn't delete the other comments.  They got copied to chat.  However, there's still more comments going on here beyond you and Eddie.